# ISS ReWrite - SEO friendly URL to Dynamic Page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, url-rewriting, seo

I'd like to use ReWrite to use SEO friendly urls that point to a dynamic url.

For example:

I want the SEO Friendly URL: www.example.com/1/Bird/

to bring up content from the dynamic URL: www.example.com/painting-details.cfm?ID=1&Type=Bird

This is the ReWrite that I've tried in the .htaccess file with no luck:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ painting-details.cfm?ID=$1&Type=$2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to get rid of the first slash.  .htaccess should read:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/$ painting-details.cfm?ID=$1&Type=$2
```